# Transform html table

Tags: php, html

Hi I have an array of movie names in alphabetical order, of which I want to create a html table of, I want to do this on the fly so I did the following:

```
echo "<div align=\"center\"><table>";   
$i=0;
foreach ($results as $entry){   
    //If first in row of 4, open row
    if($i == 0) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
    }
    //print a cell
    echo "\t<td>" . $entry . "</td>\n";
    i++;
    //if last cell in row of 4, close row
    if($i == 4) {
         echo "</tr>\n";
        $i=0;
    }
}

if($i < 4)  {
    while($i < 4) {
        echo "\t<td></td>\n";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table></div>";
```

However this builds a table which looks like:

```
entry0 | entry1 | entry2 | entry3
entry4 | entry5 | entry6 | entry7
```

How can I go about building a table like:

```
entry0 | entry3 | entry6
entry1 | entry4 | entry7
entry2 | entry5 | entry8
```

?

I'm guessing I would have to reorganise my $results array and still build the table the same way?

I'm very new to php ( a week!) so I'm not really sure how to go about this

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$results = array( 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6','e7' );

$NUM_COLUMNS = 3;

$numRows = count($results) / $NUM_COLUMNS;
if (count($results) % $NUM_COLUMNS > 0) {
  $numRows += 1;
}

echo "<div align=\"center\"><table>";
$i=0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
  echo "<tr>\n";

  $index = $i;
  for ($j = 0; $j < $NUM_COLUMNS; $j++) {
    //print a cell
    $entry = '';
    if ($index < count($results)) {
      $entry = $results[$index];
    }
    echo "\t<td>" . $entry . "</td>\n";

    $index += $numRows;
  }

  echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table></div>";
```

This is tested and includes sorting items vertically.  I would write a description, but I just got a phone call and have to go.  I will answer questions if you have any in ~1hr. (sorry!)

Comment: Thanks this works perfect, I will go through it and try to understand it now :)

Comment: The trick is that because rows don't contain sequential elements anymore, you have you loop over rows instead of items.  Therefore, you calculate the number of rows before the loop and use that to figure out which three items go in each row.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: (I did not test, but should be OK)

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$max = 3; // this is the number of columns to display

echo "<div align=\"center\"><table><tr>"; 

foreach ($results as $entry) {
    echo "<td style=\"text-align: center;\">";
    echo $entry;
    echo "</td>";

    $i++;

    if ($i == ($max)) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';

        $i = 1;
    }
}

echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

Comment: That does the same as what I already have, albeit a little simpler. I want the table to be structured differently, see my example

Comment: Ah, yes. I needed to change the beginning count of $i. I altered it, and also changed the reset if $i after adding the new row.

Comment: This still does not sort vertically, the other answer does though. thank you anyway

Comment: No worries, sorry that I missed you wanted to sort vertically or I would have included it. Take care.